# Ext Js Listview columns are not hiding or widening properly

Tags: javascript, listview, extjs

I have an Ext Js listview that I am attempting to get rid, or make my Id column smaller.  Right now it's the following code

```
    this.relList = new Ext.list.ListView({
        singleSelect: true,
        store: this.buildStore(),
        columns: [{
            header: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'Id',
            hidden: true
        }, {
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
        }]
    });
```

When this ListView is displayed, it still shows the Id column even though I told it to hide it.  Furthermore, if I change the `hidden:true` to `width: 1` to make the Id column small, the Name column no longer shows and the Id column takes up the whole listview.

How can I hide this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use the Id column at all? you can access the data via record.data or through the store itself and do not need to add it as a column

Comment: Oh I thought I could only get the Id if it was a column, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

The API does not list hidden as a valid property for each object in the columns config. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.list.ListView

From what I see, ListView doesn't support hiding columns. You may need to use a GridPanel.

Like The Scrum Meister said. If you don't need it displayed ever, it shouldn't be listed as a column.